# Why did Jesus need to die for our sins?

Tags: jesus, soteriology, resurrection, death, heaven

I feel silly asking this because I feel like it should be obvious. Why did Jesus need to die for our sins?

I am asking because this part of Christianity still confuses me. I thought Judaism taught that we will go to heaven if we believe in Judaism, but after a purification (by fire??) of our earthly sins. So Jesus' dying also guaranteed that we would go to heaven, but weren't believers guaranteed entry into heaven to begin with?

So does that mean that Jesus sacrificed himself on the cross so we would not have to go through the purification process? Is this the reason he died on the cross? Otherwise we all could have just become Jews and went through the purification process to go to heaven. Please help me understand what I am missing because I feel this can't be right.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. This site is strictly focused on Biblical exegesis, so you might like to visit our sister site [christianity.se].

Comment: A person that is nailed in a hanging position onto an upright cross is, wether s/he dies or not, dying. It is the crucifixion that is important, because it accentuates the concept of the crucified snake in the desert. This important salvational incident, was obscured in the Bible, among the many happenings the Israelites went through. Although it was supposed to, like a hidden expensive treasure in a field, be found and put into practice by posterity. The Father chose Jesus to act out this mystery on the world stage, as an eternal blessing to the world.

Comment: Take a look at Hebrews 10. In order to be saved, one needs to be cleansed of the guilt of their sins. The sacrificial system could not ultimately do this, as v.4 states: "For it is impossible for the blood of bulls and goats to take away sins." The animal sacrifice system was temporary and a sign of something greater to come, which is the sacrifice of Christ on behalf of humanity. He is a once for all sacrifice that truly can substitute the penalty of sins, being perfect and taking on humanity.